# Still getting "Schema is not a constructor", despite properly importing and exporting my Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my code. I have a review schema in a separate file called "review.js".

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../model/user');
require('mongoose-currency').loadType(mongoose);
const Currency = mongoose.Types.Currency;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let reviewSchema = new Schema();

reviewSchema.add({


    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        defualt: 0
    },


    howEasyToMake: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 5
    },

    howGoodTaste: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
    },

    wouldMakeAgain: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
    },


    comment: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },


    postedBy: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },

    reviewOf: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },

    postersCreationDate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    chefsCreationDate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    chefsId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }


});

module.exports.reviewSchema = reviewSchema;
```

I have another file called recipe.js, where I import reviewSchema and use it as an embedded schema for my Recipe model schema.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../model/user');
require('mongoose-currency').loadType(mongoose);
const Currency = mongoose.Types.Currency;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const reviewSchema = require('../model/review').reviewSchema;



let recipeSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  description: {
    type: String,
  },

  steps: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  ingredients: {
    type: Array,
    default: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
  },

  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },

  postedBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },


  reviewsOfRecipe: [reviewSchema],

  numberOfRatings: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },

  totalAddedRatings: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
  },

  reviewAverage: {
      type: Number,
      default: undefined
  },



  postersCreationDate: {
    type: Number,
    index: true
  },

  likedBy: {
      type: Array

  },

  reviewedBy: {
      type: Array
  }


});



recipeSchema.methods.updateReviewAverage = function(){

    let recipe = this;

    this.reviewAverage = this.totalAddedRatings / this.numberOfRatings;

};


let Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);

module.exports = Recipe;
```

I have another file called `recipeRouter.js` where I use `reviewSchema` to construct a review to then later insert it into the embedded `reviewsOfRecipes` array in my `Recipe` document. In my recipRouter.js file, every time my code tries to do this....

Recipe.findOne({name: req.params.name}).then((recipe) => {

```
   let review_ = new reviewSchema({
            comment: req.body.comment
            rating: req.body.score
        });

   recipe.reviewsOfRecipe.push(review_);
```

})

...I get this error.

```
 TypeError: reviewSchema is not a constructor
```

Previously, when I ran into this problem, I had the reviewSchema in the same file as my Recipe model schema. Since then, I split the two into each having their own file. And I made sure to properly export `module.exports.reviewSchema = reviewSchema;` in my `review.js` file, and made sure to have `const reviewSchema = require('../model/review').reviewSchema;` in both my `recipe.js` and `recipeRouter.js` files. Yet still this issue still comes up/ I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out what may be the issue.

Comment: You don't create an instance like that. Instead do `recipe.reviewsOfRecipe.push({ comment: req.body.comment, rating: req.body.score })`. See [sub-docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) at the bottom of the page in the mongoose documentation.. Better yet, you should learn that the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator allows you to add to arrays on the existing document on the server, rather than retrieving the document and adding to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to export `reviewSchema` like you did to the other schema (using `mongoose.model`):

```
module.exports.reviewSchema = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema);
```